# WebBrowser: BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width

Tags: vb.net

I am having issues with the following code.  BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width returns 230 even though the page is a lot bigger than this.  Therefore the majority of the page is chopped off.  If I replace BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width with an integer e.g. 2000, the entire image is captured.  The HTML file that is being captured (c:\htmlTest.txt) does contain a few JavaScript errors:

```
Public Class ImageFromHtml
    Private PageUrl As String
    Private ConvertedImage As Bitmap
    Private BrowsePage As New WebBrowser()
    Public documentText As String

    Private m_intHeight As Integer
    Public Property Height() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_intHeight
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_intHeight = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_intWidth As Integer
    Public Property Width() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_intWidth
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_intWidth = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function ConvertPage() As Bitmap
        'Me.PageUrl = PageUrl
        Dim thrCurrent As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf CreateImage))
        thrCurrent.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        thrCurrent.Start()
        thrCurrent.Join()
        'CreateImage()
        Return ConvertedImage
    End Function
    Private Sub CreateImage()

        BrowsePage.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
        'BrowsePage.Navigate(PageUrl)
        ' BrowsePage.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        'BrowsePage.Navigate("about:blank")
        BrowsePage.DocumentText = documentText
        BrowsePage.ScrollBarsEnabled = True
        AddHandler BrowsePage.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf _
WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted
        While BrowsePage.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        BrowsePage.Dispose()
    End Sub



     Private Sub WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  _
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
            'BrowsePage = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)
            BrowsePage = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)
            Height = BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height
            Width = BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width
            BrowsePage.ClientSize = New Size(BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height)
            BrowsePage.ScrollBarsEnabled = True
            BrowsePage.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
            'ConvertedImage = New Bitmap(Width, Height)
            ConvertedImage = New Bitmap(BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height)
            BrowsePage.BringToFront()
            BrowsePage.DrawToBitmap(ConvertedImage, BrowsePage.Bounds)
            'MsgBox(BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height)
            'MsgBox(BrowsePage.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width)
        End Sub



    End Class

Public Class Form1



     Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Try
                Dim objImageFromHtml As New ImageFromHtml()
                'objImageFromHtml.Height = 1000
                'objImageFromHtml.Width = 1000
                Dim SR = New StreamReader("c:\htmlTest.txt")
                objImageFromHtml.documentText = SR.ReadToEnd
                Dim Test As Bitmap = objImageFromHtml.ConvertPage()
                Test.Save("c:\Test.jpeg", _
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues potentially:

- It's possible that the web page hasn't completed a full layout and render when you use DocumentComplete in this way, especially if there is dynamic content, this won't factored into the measurements of the control (like if the JavaScript would cause more content to be loaded, shown, etc.).
- The render method you're calling isn't supported in .NET 4.0, [DrawToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserbase.drawtobitmap.aspx). So it won't render the contents of IE like you want (in fact, it just renders a large white block for me and in fact, I can't get it to render with IE9 at all in .NET 3.5sp1 or 4.0).
- The Height and Width sets in the DocumentCompleted Event aren't clear to me ... what are you trying to size there? I'd expect the BrowsePage to be the thing you're trying to resize?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I eventually found that it was the DOCTYPE attribute in the HTML that was causing the problem.  Removing the DOCTYPE attribute in the HTML resolved the problem.  Therefore the code I provided above was not enough to simulate the problem.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your code is relying on an internal method that isn't supported anymore. :)